# Expectation of $\frac{u^\top A u}{u^\top B u}$ if $u$ is multivariate standard normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, quadratic-forms

Let $u\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ follow the multivariate standard normal distribution. Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive semidefinite matrices. What is the expectation of $\frac{u^\top A u}{u^\top B u}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at [this paper](https://bit.ly/2FXJ6Be).